# GameObject with DirectionalLight component not being iluminated

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, orthographic, qcar-sdk, gameobject

I'm doing an augmented reality application using Unity3D and Vuforia. 
For each gameObject in my augmented reality scene I add a Light component to it and define it as a DirectionalLight.
In this scene the gameObjects are iluminated, but when I change to another scene (not destroying the gameObjects) they are not.
I already checked and they still have the Light component, but are not iluminated for some reason.
Do you guys have any clue of what might be the problem?

P.S.: The second scene is a normal scene with no interaction with the phone's camera. And the projection on the camera is orthographic.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail it's difficult to say with certainty, but the first thing I would suspect is whether you've culled layers on your lights or your cameras.

What "Layer" are the lights on?  Are the cameras set to ignore these layers?

What "Layers" are the lights set to illuminate?  Are the objects on these layers?